# Teams outgoing webhook response 'text' comes with webhook name

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a lightweight BOT using Team's outgoing Webhook. So when user enters a text, it should respond with the same text. Example:
User Enters a message with @botname : **@finder POC**
Return should be text entered by the user : **You have entered POC**

However it always returns with the bot name. So in my case its returning: **You have entered finder POC**

How can I omit bot name from the response. I am using python and tried replacing it with "" but it doesn't work.

Here is my code to get the text entered by the user:

```
data = req.get_json()    
sender = data['from']['name']
message = data['text']
```

And here is how I am sending the response:

```
successres = json.dumps({
            'type' : 'message',
            'text' :  "Hello" + message,
        })
```

When I use sender in place of message, it gives proper response.

Sample screenshot:

[image]

Any help.

It should return only 'SOP' but it returns 'finder SOP'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in the bot framework to remove an @ mention, which you would use in this case to remove the mention of the bot itself. See here for more info: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/blob/fcfd6a25c23c75fa524b373232b1a174cec41e98/libraries/botbuilder-core/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py#L380

Comment: is there anyway that I silently just receive that web hook request and not reply back, if I leave it empty or just respond with 200 status code, it send a message to the teams: "Sorry, there was a problem encountered with your request"

Comment: I'm not totally following you. Can you post it, with more details, as a proper question rather than just here as a comment?